# Stack overflow error when dynamically generated content in slidejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, stack-overflow, slidesjs

When I generate dynamically the contents of second slide and add it to DOM, am getting 'Stack overflow error' while calling $('#slides1 .next').click();

[slidejs: how to control two slides with same previous next button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743445/slidejs-how-to-control-two-slides-with-same-previous-next-button)